# How to add Slugify to ElasticSearch?

Tags: python, django, search, elasticsearch, full-text-search

There is a Russian word for "pizza" = "пицца" and they are very similar since:

```
"p" equals to "п"
"i" equals to "и"
"z" equals to "ц"
"z" equals to "ц"
"a" equals to "а"
```

So when I'm searching for "пицца" I must get all results with "pizza" as result.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved and the way it solved is not what i expected but still, it just works, here is the solution:

```
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "filter": {
            "ru_synonym": {
                "type": "synonym",
                "synonyms": [
                    "pizza, пицца"
                ]
            }
        },
        "analyzer": {
            "ru_analyzer": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "ru_synonym"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with that solution though is that you need to add each synonym explicitly. Not a problem if you just have a couple but if there are a lot...

Comment: In that case, this might help - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.4/analysis-icu-transform.html